# Function without return type specified in C

Tags: c, function-declaration

I came across this piece of code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main( )
{
 int i = 5;
 workover(i);
 printf("%d",i);
}
workover(i)
int i;
{
 i = i*i;
 return(i);
}
```

I want to know how the declaration of the function "workover" is valid? What happens when we don't mention the return type of a function? (can we return anything?).The parameter is also just a variable name, how does this work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you do not specify a return type or parameter type, C will implicitly declare it as `int`.

This is a "feature" from the earlier versions of C (C89 and C90), but is generally considered bad practice nowadays. Since the C99 standard (1999) does no longer allow this, a compiler targeting C99 or later will likely give you a warning similar to the following:

```
program.c: At top level:
program.c:8:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
 workover(i)
 ^
```

Answer (score 4):

The function declaration syntax was used in older versions of C, and is still valid, so the code fragment "workover(i) int i;" is equivalent to "workover(int i)". Although, I think it may still generate warnings or even errors, depending on what compiler options you use.

Comment: It's *not* still valid: "[*C99 is, for the most part, backward compatible with C89, but it is stricter in some ways. **In particular, a declaration that lacks a type specifier no longer has `int` implicitly assumed.***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Design)" That's why a warning may be generated.

Comment: Those two are not exactly equivalent; `workover(i) int i;`  is not a prototype but `workover(int i)` is.  It is similar to the difference between `int main()` and `int main(void)`

Answer (score 1):

When I compile your code as `$ gcc common.c -o common.exe -Wall`
*(Trying it over Cygwin Terminal as I don't have my linux system with me right now)*

I get following warnings:

```
common.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
main( )
^
common.c: In function ‘main’:
common.c:6:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘workover’ [-Wimplicit-f                  unction-declaration]
workover(i);
^
common.c: At top level:
common.c:9:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
workover(i)
^
common.c: In function ‘main’:
common.c:8:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
```

1. The first and the third one says, `return type defaults to ‘int’` which means that if you don't specify a return type, compiler will implicitly declare it as `int`.
2. The second one says, `implicit declaration of function ‘workover’` since the compiler doesn't know what `workover` is.
3. Third warning is pretty simple to understand and will disappear if you fix the first one.

You should do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int workover(int);

int i;

int main(void)
{
    int i = 5;
    workover(i);
    printf("%d",i);     //prints 5
    return 0;
}

int workover(int i)
{
    i = i*i;    //i will have local scope, so after this execution i will be 25;
    return(i);  //returns 25
}
```