# No Return type for function?

Tags: c, int, return-value, return-type

In the program i have not mentioned return type for function `fullon` but the code still runs and `output: "7"` is printed. How did this works even when i did not mentioned any return type? i have searched it on this site and i am not able to find any suitable answer.I am still a beginner so i don't have much background of C.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  fullon(int);

int main()
 {

   int b;
   int x = 5 ;
   b = fullon(x);

   printf("%d" , b);
  }

fullon(int y)
    {

      return y+2;

    }
```

Update 1 :

```
#include<stdio.h>
fullon(float);

int main()
 {

float b;
int x = 5 ;
float f = 3.5;
b = fullon(f);


printf("%f" , b);

        }
 fullon(float y)
    {

            return y;

                }
```

`Output is 3.000000`

Comment: @Mike Your explanation makes no sense.

Comment: @Mike `man 3 printf` => `int printf(const char *format, ...);`, anyway even though *int* would not be indicated, by default C returns an int. You may use it, or leave it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back in the 1980s, pre-standard C (sometimes called K&R C, where K&R refers to the names of Kernighan and Ritchie, who created the language and wrote the first C language manual) allowed function declarations like this one:

```
noreturntype() 
{ 
//returns something the size of an int
/* do something */
return 456;
 }
```

So even though the function had no return type, it was allowed to return anything that had the same number of bytes as an int on a given implementation. (For instance, if a 16-bit machine had 16-bit integers and 16-bit pointers, it was allowed to return either an int or a pointer in such a function.)

When the C standard was created, these old-style declarations were kept for backwards compatibility with existing programs. (As a matter of fact, even modern compilers tend to accept old-style function declaration along with a warning).

Answer (score 0):

In C, functions have an implied return type of `int` if it's not specified. This is an ancient quirk and absolutely should not be used; I'm surprised your compiler isn't giving you a warning about it.

Comment: It gave me this warning..... data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]|

Comment: So you mean even if i do not mention an return type..I would still be able to return integer. ??

Comment: @Suraj Jain Modern compilers often allow this but they do give a warning..(most of them).

Comment: @Suraj Jain I have explained the reason in my answer.No return type was used in the pre-standard edition to return an integer.A return type was not compulsory.But in the standard version of C,they still maintained the support for this so that the old programs don't face a problem.Otherwise,all the old programs would require a modification.

Comment: @Suraj Jain  I read the question and I have given you the most accurate answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98460/discussion-between-suraj-jain-and-mathews-mathai).

Comment: @MathewsMathai So if i return float it will convert to integer??

Comment: @Suraj Jain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542092/function-without-return-type-specified-in-c

Comment: @Suraj Jain If you don't mention a return type,it implicity treats it as an integer.So possibly,it may convert float to integer.

Comment: @Suraj Jain  I would suggest you try out returning float with out mentioning a data type in the function declaration.This would help you a lot.

Comment: i did that see the question again.. It converts float to integer.

Comment: @Suraj Jain ...So sorry..I was using the app and I found your edit just now.So then,it's clear right??...It converts float to integer..cause it impicity treats the returned value as an integer since there is no return type.

Comment: @MathewsMathai It is really ok. It is clear now. No return type is treated as integer. So float get converted to integer.Thanks a lot .