# Assigning Data type to a User Defined Function

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

I'm new to programming and I was pondering about it.

In C language when a Function is declared by the user. What happens if the data type of the function is not assigned. My question is basically that what is the difference between a function like these:

```
int main()
{
    statements.....
}

main()
{
    statements.....
}
```

what happens if we assign the data type? what happens if we don't?
Any help. Please
Thank You.

Comment: The first version is a function that returns an `int`. The second one is incorrect C.

Comment: It would be a syntax error according to C11. But K&R C allowed this and the return type defaulted to `int`. Most compilers today still allow this for backward compatibility.

Comment: Please: (A) Turn on warnings. (B) Search before posting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function without return type specified in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542092/function-without-return-type-specified-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's referred to as the implicit int rule. Essentially, it assumes it's an int. Though this is not in the C standard (as of C99).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11064331/9536611) for a more detailed answer.